# Select multiple rows with duplicates limited to unique meta rows MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to make a quite specific query on MySQL database, I will start with table example:

```
+----+---------------+------------------------------------+----------+
| id | data          | pattern_key                        | hash     |
+----+---------------+------------------------------------+----------+
|  1 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | ABCDEFGH |
|  2 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | ABCDEFGH |
|  3 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | ABCDEFGH |
|  4 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | HGFEDCBA |
|  5 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | HGFEDCBA |
|  6 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | OPQRSTUW |
|  7 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | ABCDEFGH |
|  8 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | ABCDEFGH |
|  9 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | IJKLMNOP |
| 10 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | ABCDEFGH |
+----+---------------+------------------------------------+----------+
```

As you can see I have column data and pattern_key, which are irrelevant in this moment. What matters is hash column, which allows for identical values, ie.: ABCDEFGH. What I want to do is select 5 rows ordered by ID descending, but including duplicates on hash column and only when they are after each other. Result of query for this table should be:

```
+----+---------------+------------------------------------+----------+
| id | data          | pattern_key                        | hash     |
+----+---------------+------------------------------------+----------+
| 10 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | ABCDEFGH |
|  9 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | IJKLMNOP |
|  8 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | ABCDEFGH |
|  7 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | ABCDEFGH |
|  6 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | OPQRSTUW |
|  5 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | HGFEDCBA |
+----+---------------+------------------------------------+----------+
```

We have 6 records, not 5 as limited, but row 7 was included, because row 8 has the same hash value. This behaviour has to disregard count of duplicates as long they are after each other, so if we were to order by id ascending, we would get:

```
+----+---------------+------------------------------------+----------+
| id | data          | pattern_key                        | hash     |
+----+---------------+------------------------------------+----------+
|  1 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | ABCDEFGH |
|  2 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | ABCDEFGH |
|  3 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | ABCDEFGH |
|  4 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | HGFEDCBA |
|  5 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | HGFEDCBA |
|  6 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | OPQRSTUW |
|  7 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | ABCDEFGH |
|  8 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | ABCDEFGH |
|  9 | {"user":true} | NOTIFICATIONHUB::SYSTEM            | IJKLMNOP |
+----+---------------+------------------------------------+----------+
```

as we have 3 ABCDEFGHs (1 unique meta row I think), 2 HGFEDCBAs (2 unique meta row), 1 OPQRSTUW (3rd unique row), 2 ABCDEFGHs (4 unique metarow, as those are divided from first 3 ABCDEFGHs with other hashes) and one IJKLMNOP.

I was thinking about group by but it crops duplicates and I want them included in data set. Any ideas?

Thanks to @Uueerdo I've come up with that solution (yes, JOIN was required anyway):

```
SET @i := 0;
SET @lastHash := '';
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT notification_real_id AS id, data, pattern_key, @i := IF(hash <> @lastHash, @i + 1, @i) AS hashGroup, @lastHash := hash AS hash
   FROM
     ( SELECT notifications.id AS notification_real_id,
              data,
              pattern_key,
              hash
      FROM notifications
      INNER JOIN notifications_users ON notifications.id = notifications_users.notification_id
      WHERE notifications_users.user_id = 1) AS subJoin
   ORDER BY notification_real_id DESC) AS subQ
WHERE hashGroup <= 5;
```

Comment: So, to rephrase your question, you want to `LIMIT` the results of the query by the number of *unique* hashes? For example, you want a maximum of 5 distinct hashes, but that could be 5 rows or could be 8 rows... Is that correct?

Comment: Yes! I want select UNTIL 5 distinct hashes are found, but the problem is that they can repeat (so not really distinct) if only they are separated from previous 'same hash' group with another row with another hash.

Comment: Will a stored procedure suffice?

Comment: if this is mysql, which it is, you can group by hash, sort by id desc and select having max(id), then limit 5. mysql doesnt have the same check as mssql which that wouldnt work with

Comment: I wouldn't like to use stored procedure as that's a part of a plugin for a CMS system, and I don't want to handle addition and removal of stored procedures.

Comment: @Christian, is that possible in one query?

Comment: @Egregore, im actually not sure what you're looking for because i thought you just wanted the desc 5 unique hashes, but then your questions thrown me off... ill put an answer below and you tell me if its what you want :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have time to verify it is exactly correct, but something like this should work:

```
SET @i := 0;
SET @lastHash := '';
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT id, data, pattern_key
   , @i := IF(hash <> @lastHash, @i + 1, @i) AS hashGroup
   , @lastHash := hash
  FROM table
  ORDER BY id DESC
) AS subQ
WHERE hashGroup <= 5
;
```

Alternatively (no variables required) *(not recommended: not as reliable without data hacks, not as flexible with joins, and most likely much slower)*:

```
SELECT * 
FROM the_table  
WHERE id > (
   SELECT MAX(id) AS lastID    
   FROM the_table
   GROUP BY hash 
   ORDER BY lastID DESC LIMIT 5, 1
  )
;
```

Comment: @Egregore did you try this yet?

Comment: This in fact works beautifully and I've found way to use stored procedures, so I am accepting this answer. Thanks to everybody for help!

Comment: i dont think this needs to be in a SP

Comment: I would love to use one query to do this and not pollute CMS database with stored procedure, I would love not to use variables too, but I can't think out how to do it in any other way.

Comment: I could make one that doesn't use variables, but it would be rather hideous. This kinda thing: SELECT blah FROM blah_table WHERE blah_id > (SELECT MIN(lastID) FROM (SELECT a_field, MAX(ID) AS lastID FROM blah_table GROUP BY a_field ORDER BY lastID DESC LIMIT 6));

Comment: @Uueerdo, I have updated question with how it looks now (with join subquery on pivot table). Any ideas how to integrate that alternate version without variables? It is returning empty set right now.

Comment: @Egregore, Assuming you want the rows of the most recent 5 hashes of user_id = 1, I think you'd need to put the join and where condition in the SELECT MAX() subquery and it's outer query.

Comment: Also, with regards to your current query, was putting the @lastHash calculations in the outer query faster, or did it not work out quite right when done on the subquery?

Comment: @Uueerdo, I have analyzed that query without variables you have provided and it does have some shortcomings comparing with the first, variable-requiring version. For instance - it returns empty dataset if less than 5 records are available for subquery. And more, it requires 2 joins instead of one, as both inner query and outer query needs to search through join-restricted data set. I don't know if query optimizer can disregard that and execute only one join select instead of two, considering they are identical. First solution included all duplicates of last record, second one gets only first.

Comment: @Egregore, I wouldn't have normally suggested the second one (as it does complicate such criteria, but also because I have an irrational distaste for subqueries in WHERE clauses); but it is the best I could think of without variable use. I can see the problem with not enough records, now that you point it out. But I am not sure why it would exhibit the other unusual behavior you mentioned. For one, the subquery should be getting the last id of the last hash you **don't** want (LIMIT 5, 1 should give you the 6th hash's, so > than that should include all of the 5th most recent hash's records.)

Comment: @Uueerdo, take a look: http://i.imgur.com/sWdLiXs.png, http://i.imgur.com/5Js3RQo.png < your query, problem is, if there are less then 6 hash groups, this query fails and returns empty set: http://i.imgur.com/013l7en.png < 4 groups

Comment: @Egregore, I understand that problem, and I can't think of a way to get around it short of adding some sort of dummy records to make sure everyone has at least 6 hashes starting out. What I don't understand is why, when it does have sufficient (6) hashes, the last hash's duplicates would get omitted.

Comment: I might have changed something in limits while checking that problem and came up with wrong conclusion, now it works without problems. Adding dummy records is a dirty hack, I'd rather create a stored procedure within migrations via direct access to database. What hurts, is that I can't use CMS ORM to do that anyhow, so now I'm thinking about redesign of that part.